# Is filter properties are not supported by the MSAA following technology in codedui?

Tags: c#, winforms, coded-ui-tests

I am testing a winform application and I am having trouble with some controls. 
when I spy on a combobox object I can not see any search properties, so I decided to use filterproperties but I get below error. so as I understand, I can not use filterproperties with winform applications ?

> System.ArgumentException: Filter properties are not supported by the
>   following technology: MSAA. To search for a control, you must remove
>   the filter properties.

When I spy, I see only Text is uniqe for comboboxes, here is my code, I dont know if its correct, I can not see Text propery, this is not accepted. `Wincombobox.PropertyNames.Text`, so I used directly as `FilterProperties["text"]` Can somone show me exact usage ?

```
WinComboBox uIEPeriodComboBox = this.UIProMANAGEDorukOtomasWindow2.UIMachineHistoryWindow.UIEPeriodComboBox;
uIEPeriodComboBox.FilterProperties["text"] = "Last 2 hours";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this link](https://willcodefor.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/search-and-filter-properties-of-coded-ui/) about search and filter properties for a explanation.  Filter properties apparently only work if the technology is "web". So they can not be used for "MSAA". If you added your control to the UIMap, you can check what search properties your coded UI test uses to uniquely identify your control:

1. right click that control in your UIMap
2. Click "properties"
3. In the properties window, search for the "Search Properties" row.
4. Click on the "..." button to view the "Edit Search Properties" window.

If you already changed/added some of those properties trough the VS UI, and your coded UI test fails to find the control, you could always try to re-add the control to your UIMap with the inspector tool.